# Shell Script to check for subdirectory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, time, date

A. I used the following code to get the modified date of a file. But this is also selecting the subdirectories and thus returning an error. How can I fix this?

```
for file in $1/*; do
        echo `stat -c %y $file | cut -d ' ' -f1`
done
```

`$1` is the directory I am passing.

B. Also is there any way to do this thing. That I need to pass a directory and date range as command-line argument and list the file and modified date which lies in this date range.

Eg `output.sh /home/user/desktop 2014-10-07 2014-11-17` should list all the files in this directory which are modified in this time interval.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted on [ubuntu.se] and [unix.se] ([don't do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding part A of your question, here is a [reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) to the standard file tests.

In particular, what you can do is:

```
for file in $1/*; do
    [ ! -d "$file" ] && echo `stat -c %y $file | cut -d ' ' -f1`
done
```

As for part B, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052318/how-to-get-files-listed-within-specific-time-range) stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

For part A, a more efficient approach:

```
find $1 -maxdepth 1 ! -type d -exec stat -c "%y" {} + | cut -d' ' -f1
```

`find` is excellent at filtering out based on type, and `exec` with `+` should run far fewer `stat` process. Piping the whole output to `cut` means we have to run `cut` only once. And there is really no need to do

```
echo `some command`
```

The only benefit is converting multi-line output to single line, which is not applicable to your case anyway.